How to Access GKE Private Master from VPN in Hub VPC with Peering
I am currently facing an issue with accessing the master of a private GKE cluster on Google Cloud Platform. Here’s the configuration I have:
terraform code:
resource "google_container_cluster" "private_cluster" {
  name     = "name"
  location = var.zone
  network  = gke_vpc_self_link
  subnetwork = gke_subnet_self_link

  enable_shielded_nodes = true
  remove_default_node_pool = true
  initial_node_count       = 1

  private_cluster_config {
    enable_private_endpoint = true
    enable_private_nodes    = true
    master_ipv4_cidr_block  = "172.16.0.0/28"
  }

Network Architecture:

VPC Hub: Contains a VM with Pritunl VPN server.
VPC Spoke: Contains the private GKE cluster.
VPC Peering: Established between VPC Hub and VPC Spoke.

Issue
I have a Pritunl VPN server running in the VPC Hub. The problem is that the master of the GKE cluster in the VPC Spoke is not accessible using the private IP obtained from the VPN in the VPC Hub. This is because VPC peering in Google Cloud does not support transit routing, meaning the IPs from the VPN cannot directly access the GKE master unless they belong to the same VPC.
Requirements

Access the GKE master from my local machine via the VPN in the VPC Hub.
Avoid setting up a VPN in the VPC Spoke.

Tried Solutions

VPC Peering: Established peering between VPC Hub and VPC Spoke, but it does not support transit routing.

Desired Solution
Looking for a method to enable access from my local machine (via the VPN in the VPC Hub) to the GKE master in the VPC Spoke without having to set up another VPN in the VPC Spoke.
What are the recommended practices or configurations to achieve this setup? Any suggestions on using a transit gateway, routes, or other methods to resolve this issue would be highly appreciated.
#Environment Details

Google Cloud Platform (GCP)
GKE Cluster (Private)
Pritunl VPN in VPC Hub
VPC Peering between Hub and Spoke


Because VPC peerings are not transitive, you do not have to use them! The current solution (by waiting the PSC compliance of the GKE control plane) is to set up a Cloud VPN between your hub and spoke. And this time, it will work. not elegant, but you have no really other managed solution (an ugliest one is to create a VM with 2 NIC, one in each VPC, and to forward the traffic through this VM). If you can rebuild your network, you can also use a shared VPC architecture, but you will have to break all the existing deployment...

Can you check this comment in this Feature request, if it resolves your issue.

I have also explored the possibility of shared VPC. But I have understood that this is useful for when I have multiple projects, in which I want to share the same networking configurations in all of them. Is it more advisable to use this shared VPC in GCP or is Hub-Spoke a good solution? I intend to isolate Staging and Prod as much as possible, and try to have only one vpc to handle all the traffic.

Actually, the new release on Network Connectivity Center could solve your problem. I faced the same issue and decided to pay for support from Engineer of Google Cloud.
It is called NCC PSC propagated connection. It will help you in hub and spoke architecture (custom VPC peered to Shared VPC which has GKE). Network from the
GKE PSC route will be propagated and can be routed from the Custom VPC.
You can see the new feature here (Released Jun 14, 2024)
https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/network-connectivity-center/concepts/psc-propagated-connection-overview
If you find it is helpful, please give me an upvote (I need 50 reputations to comment on the post, thanks)

Anybody tried to connect from AWS VPN in shared VPC setup.

You mean s2s vpn right? s2s will work for sure, because it is oldschool method to act with transitive routing...

Currently the GKE provides DNS-based endpoint and according to GCP should be used as default access method:

The DNS-based endpoint gives a unique DNS or fully qualified domain name (FQDN) for each cluster control plane. This DNS name can be used to access your control plane. The DNS name resolves to an endpoint that is accessible from any network reachable by Google Cloud APIs, including on-premises or other cloud networks. Enabling the DNS-based endpoint eliminates the need for a bastion host or proxy nodes to access the control plane from other VPC networks or external locations.


To access the control plane endpoint, you need to configure IAM roles and policies, and authentication tokens. For more details on the exact permissions required, see Customize your network isolation.


In addition to IAM policies and tokens, you can also configure IP or network-based controls with VPC Service Controls to secure access to the control plane. VPC Service Controls add another layer of access security with context-aware access based on attributes such as network origin. VPC Service Controls let you configure which networks can access the DNS endpoint. Using both IAM policies and VPC Service Controls to secure access to the DNS-based endpoint provides a multi-layer security model for your cluster control plane. VPC Service Controls are used by all Google Cloud APIs, aligning the security configuration of your clusters with your data hosted in all other Google Cloud APIs.

So from my understanding this endpoint works right now more like all others APIs for GCP (but is of course some random URL) and mentioned VPC Service Controls should be used to provide increased security (if you need that) to this API.
You will find more abut this under those links:
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/network-isolation#dns-based_endpoint
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/latest/network-isolation

The GKE control plane is deployed in Google-managed VPC, not in your spoke VPC.
To access the control plane you need to establish a VPN connection between hub VPC and spoke VPC as mentioned in the comments.
Another solution is to use the bastion VM deployed in your spoke VPC and SSH to it from your hub VPC. And then connect to control plane from bastion host. More - https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/private-cluster-bastion
Third solution is to use External endpoint access with authorized networks enabled. https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/private-cluster-concept#overview
There is some option to use PSC to connect to GKE control plane but for now this PSC endpoint can be deployed only in the same VPC where your node pools are deployed so its not very useful in your case. Keep in mind that this is default for some newer versions of clusters:

Private or public clusters that meet any of the following conditions, use Private Service Connect to privately connect nodes and the control plane:
New public clusters in version 1.23 on or after March 15, 2022. New
private clusters in version 1.29 after January 28, 2024.

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/network-overview#public-cluster-psc

Vpn will work for sure, but it have management overhead and also bandwidth limit, 2 tunnels with 1GiBps each, when the NCC is now support PSC propagation without the limit and addional operational cost.
